# AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'massage_handler'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token="")

@bot.massage_handler(comands=["start"])

def first (massage):
key = telebot.types.ReplayKeyboardMarkup (True,False)
key.row("Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2")
```

При запуске пишет:

```
"E:\python\bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    @bot.massage_handler(comands=["start"])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'massage_handler'
```

Comment: Могли бы и отметить ответ как решение, раз уж использовали его в другом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Если планируется обработчик сообщений, а не массажа, я бы всё-таки советовал `message_handler`:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token="")
@bot.message_handler(comands=["start"])

def first (message):
key = telebot.types.ReplayKeyboardMarkup (True,False)
key.row("Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2")
```